# Google Drive Api v3 "File not found"

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

During my work with the Google Drive Api v3, I am facing an issue:

If I make a call to retrieve the file list, in the response I can see, among others:

```
{ id: '1XYlwukNmzUrHRCh05pb9OeD1nnZdDjJU', name: 'file5.zip' },
```

so now I am using the `fileId` in the response above to try to delete:

```
const deleteFileById = (fileId) => {

    console.log(`File id is ${fileId}`);
    const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', authorization });

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            drive.files.delete({
                auth: authorization,
                fileId: fileId,
            }, (err, res) => {
                
                if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
                resolve("File has been deleted");

            });

        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

And getting as a response:

```
The API returned an error: Error: File not found: 1XYlwukNmzUrHRCh05pb9OeD1nnZdDjJU.
```

So, at this point I would say that is weird.....

Comment: I think that in this case, it is required to confirm the script of `a call to retrieve the file list` including the authorization script. So can you provide it?

Comment: @Tanaikem the script to get the list + the authorization are literally a copy/paste from the docs at https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs. the only I have changed is the scope, to grant me full access I use scope like: `const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];`

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, when the file of `1XYlwukNmzUrHRCh05pb9OeD1nnZdDjJU` can be retrieved by the sample script of Quickstart with the scope in your replying, I think that your script works. So, for example, when you delete `token.json` file and reauthorize the scope again, what result will you obtain? When this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code i used. It works but runs a little fast sometimes.  You dont need to add authorization to the call to the api its already part of the service.

```
async function deleteFiles(auth) {

    const driveService = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});

    let response = await driveService.files.list({
        q: "parents in '10krlloIS2i_2u_ewkdv3_1NqcpmWSL1w'",
        fields: 'files(id)'
    })

    const files = response.data.files;
    if (files.length) {
        console.log('Files:');
        files.map((file) => {
            console.log(`${file.id}`);
            driveService.files.delete({
                "fileId": file.id
            })
                .then(() => console.log('FileDeleted'))
                .catch((err) => console.error('failed' + err));
        });
    } else {
        console.log('No files found.');
    }
}
```